# what does the np.transpose function do?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, axis

recently doing a course on numpy, I encountered this problem and am finding difficulty understanding some concepts therefore if someone could help me.Some websites state that it interchanges the axis but what does that actually mean?

Comment: For example, in 2D matrix, it changes rows into columns, columns into rows..

Comment: so basically if the dimensions are(1,20), it will change it into (20,1)?

Comment: Right. You can try with some code and arrays to test by yourself.

Comment: Please explore in [numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html)

Answer (score 0):

Transpose is a general mathematical operation which is implemented by numpy. It flips a matrix over its main diagonal(starts from top-left and goes to the bottom-right). So if your matrix is,

```
a b
c d
e f
```

transposing it will flip it over the diagonal a-d, resulting in a transposed matrix as,

```
a c e
b d f
```

Note: the main diagonal still stays the same, so that if you transpose the transposed matrix it will result in the original matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two 2D `np.array`s - `A` and `B` - where `B` was created by transposing `A`, then for every `i`, `j` being legal indices for `A`: `A[i][j] == B[j][i]` does holds `True`.